# Lifting state up in React from all fields in a form as an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a `Letter` component, composed of `Address`, `LetterText` and `Signature`.
The state is kept at the `Letter` level, being the parent.
The method to update the state is propagated to the children as props.

This works well for `LetterText` which is basically a `textarea`, but I can't quite get it working for the Address, given it's made of many different `input` tags.

`LetterText` looks like this:

```
export default function Letter(props) {

  const [letter, setLetter] = useState({
    address: {},
    text: "",
    signature: null
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setLetter({
      ...letter,
      [event.target.name]: value
    });
  }

return (
      <div>
      <Address name="address", letterAddress={letter.address} setLetterAddress={handleChange}/>
      <LetterText name="text", letterText={letter.text}, setLetterText={handleChange}/>
      <LetterSignature />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The `LetterText` component (working) is as follows:

```
export default function LetterText(props) {
    const { name, letterText, setLetterText, ...rest } = props;
    return (
      <textarea
        name={name}
        value={letterText}
        onChange={setLetterText}
        {...rest}
      >
      </textarea>
    );
  }
```

The `Address` component is the one I'm struggling with. As you can see I thought about wrapping the `setLetterAddress` function and do some data massaging. However, this leads to the "
`letter.address` object to have a pair `undefined: undefined` in it. Here's my (not working attempt):

```
export default function LetterAddress(props) {
  const { name, letterAddress, setLetterAddress, ...rest } = props;

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { eName, eValue } = event.target;
    let address = { ...letterAddress };
    address[eName] = eValue;
    const e = { target: { name: name, value: address } };
    setLetterAddress(e);
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        Full name
        <input
          type="text"
          name="fullName"
          value={letterAddress.fullName}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Address
        <input
          type="text"
          name="addressLine"
          value={letterAddress.addressLine}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
}
```

How can I lift the status up from the `Address` component nicely?

Comment: Why don't you keep the address state separately ?

Comment: It returns undefined because `event.target` doesn't have `eName` and `eValue` properties. The `event` is a built-in parameter that is automatically attached to input fields' listeners.

Comment: @SüleymanGÜNDÜZ I want to keep the state all in one place. Eventually in the `Letter` component there'll be a submit button to collect all the information and store it in a database.

Comment: But still you can keep them seperately and after when you are gonna submit, you can make one big object again, it looks easier for me.

Comment: @jstarnate Silly me. Good point. I should destructure `event` and use new names there. Something like `const { name: eName, value: eValue } = event.target`.

Comment: @SüleymanGÜNDÜZ it sounds definitely easier, but how would you achieve that? Each component has its own state: what should the button do to collect all the states?

Comment: @Jir `const { name: eName, value: eValue } = event.target`

Comment: @Jir In LetterAddress, I suggest that you add a submit button and pass the data thru submit event because you have only one event for two input fields and whenever you type on either input field, it would only save either the full name or the address, not both.

Comment: @jstarnate I see what you're saying. However, if I add a submit button in `LetterAddress` I can't collect the state for the other two components (`LetterSignature` and `LetterText`), which I also need bundled together with the address. So the submit button has to be at the parent level (`Letter`) unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Jir I think you should make another event in Letter just for LetterAddress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216635/discussion-between-jir-and-jstarnate).